# Clusters for Yandex MapKit on Swift

Tags: swift, yandexmapkit

Большая необходимость реализовать кластеризацию на Yandex Map. Как лучше всего реализовать это на Swift? Только начинаю осваивать. Может есть у кого примеры. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь можно посмотреть пример: https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-ios-demo/blob/master/MapKitDemo/ClusteringViewController.swift